# Error con array en update en PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Muy buenas comunidad, tengo un problema, cuando intento insertar un update con un array que recupero de la variable sesion solo me inserta el ultimo elemento del array, utilizo var_dump y si recupera todos los elementos de la variable sesión

codigo:

```
    <?php
session_start();
$folio =( $_SESSION['folio']);
include_once('../config/conexion.php');
$database = new Conexion();
$db = $database->open();

$cantidad= $_SESSION['cantidad'];

$sucursal = $_SESSION['sucursal'];

$almacen = $_SESSION['almacen'];


 $contador = count($cantidad);
 for ($i = 0; $i < $contador; $i++ ) {
 
   $actualizar_masivo="UPDATE almacenes SET cantidad = '" . $cantidad[$i] . "'   where almacen = 1 ";
   if($db->query($actualizar_masivo) == true){

     echo "actualizacion correcta";
     var_dump($cantidad[$i]);
  }else 
   {
     echo "error al actualizar";
   }
 }
```

y esto me devuelve el codigo en el navegador `actualizacion correctastring(2) "12" actualizacion correctastring(2) "12" actualizacion correctastring(2) "32" actualizacion correctastring(2) "12" actualizacion correctastring(2) "43" actualizacion correctastring(2) "12" actualizacion correctastring(2) "21" actualizacion correctastring(2) "12" actualizacion correctastring(2) "32" actualizacion correctastring(2) "54" actualizacion correctastring(2) "32" actualizacion correctastring(2) "23" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "122" actualizacion correctastring(3) "322"`

pero en la base de datos solo me actualiza en todos los campos con el ultimo registro

Comment: claramente no inserta, por que estas actualizando...

Comment: Veo la edicion, pero estás actualizando solo la cantidad del almacen 1 y ya... no entiendo que buscar cambiar

Comment: Gracias por responder, el problema es que todos los campos se me actualizan con el ultimo elemento del array que es 322

Comment: Te lo estoy diciendo amigo, estás actualizando TODOS los almacen 1, con el ULTIMO dato (322) que te llega... hay un problema de lógica en eso.

Comment: Es decir, estoy seguro que falta algo, por ej, para que tienes sucursal ?

Comment: ya veo gracias voy a revisar el codigo de nuevo, sucursal solo para hacer mas especifico donde voy insertar el update, pero como solo tengo por el momento en mi BD una sucursal no lo pongo, mi unica duda era como puedo hacer para que se inserten los demas y no solo el ultimo, igual creo que me debe de faltar codigo en el for para llegar a eso, gracias por responder

Comment: El problema lo tienes en la consulta, tienes que sumar el valor nuevo al que tenías antes: SET cantidad = cantidad + '" . $cantidad[$i] . "'

Comment: ya vi mi error, eran varios, uno fue que no especifique bien en los datos que se van actualizar, por lo cual exporte el array de otro campo, en ahi especifique el campo a actualizar, gracias por sus respuestas a este nuv